# printing kinect point cloud data alone gives garbage

Tags: ros, kinect, msg, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have subscribed to /camera/depth/points to get the PointCloud2 data from kinect. When I try to print the PointCloud2 data alone leaving out the headers, height and width etc i get a pool of garbage values. How do i print the 'data' field alone.? I am able to get the output  without any garbage if i print the entire msg.

Here is my code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import roslib
import rospy
from sensor_msgs.msg import PointCloud2

def callback(msg):
    print len((data.data))
    print msg.data
    listener.unregister()

def kinect_depth():
    rospy.init_node('kinect_depth', anonymous=True)
    global listener 
    listener = rospy.Subscriber("/camera/depth/points", PointCloud2, callback)
    rospy.spin()

if __name__=='__main__':
    kinect_depth()
```

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/202189/printing-kinect-point-cloud-data-alone-gives-garbage/) by [gaussian](https://answers.ros.org/users/21014/gaussian/) on ROS Answers with karma: 88 on 2015-02-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The PointCloud2 is packed into a format that is not automatically unpacked. [sensor_msgs/point_cloud2.py](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/sensor_msgs/html/point__cloud2_8py.html) can help you unpack the data (though it is a bit slow).

Alternatively, if you just want depth, and not x,y,z points, you could subscribe to the depth image and use cv_bridge to get the data.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2015-02-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gaussian](https://answers.ros.org/users/21014/gaussian/) on 2015-02-01**:
Thanks for your reply. I will look into it. I want the x,y,z data without converting the pointcloud2 into .pcd file. Is it possible to get that?

**Comment by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) on 2015-02-01**:
Yes, that's what the functions in point_cloud2.py do.

**Comment by [gaussian](https://answers.ros.org/users/21014/gaussian/) on 2015-02-02**:
@Dan Lazewatsky If I use the latter method of converting the depthimage into grayscale image, how can I convert that into depth in some unit. As the grayscale value in the image are relative to largest depth. Am i right? Is there any const conversion factor between grayscale value and deptin in 'm'?

**Comment by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) on 2015-02-02**:
Using openni_camera at least, depth images contain `uint16` depths in mm.